# How can i convert a string in to a valid html list using regexp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, angularjs

I am working on a `angularjs` app.

I am receiving the data as an array from back-end. I need to convert that in to a html list. (using `li`) but how can i do that?

here is the array `string` i am getting :

```
"1. Submittals in progress 2. Structural works in progress in S2 & S3 3. Structural works in progress in N4. 4. Childrens Mall pedestal and steel fabrication."
```

I would like to convert this in to Un-ordered list like this:

```
<ul>
<li> Submittals in progress </li> //see the number removed.
<li> Structural works in progress in S2 & S3 </li>
<li> Structural works in progress in N4. </li> //end has the dot
<li> Childrens Mall pedestal and steel fabrication. </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple regex to split the string and then put ng-repeat on the li in html

You can seek help from **angular js docs or stack overflow** on how to use ng-repeat

```
var str = "1. Submittals in progress 2. Structural works in progress in S2 & S3 3. Structural works in progress in N4. 4. Childrens Mall pedestal and steel fabrication.";   //sample string

var result = str.split(/^\d+\.+\s+|\s\d\.\s/); //just skip text at index zero
//use ng-repeat and print in whatever way you wanted

result = str.split(/(^\d+\.+\s+|\s\d\.\s)/);  //if numbers are also required
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
var s = "1. Submittals in progress 2. Structural works in progress in S2 & S3 3. Structural works in progress in N4. 4. Childrens Mall pedestal and steel fabrication.";

var r = "<ul>\n" +
        s.replace(/\b\d+\.\s+(.+?)\s*(?=\b\d+\. |\s*$)/g, "<li> $1 </li>\n") +
        "</ul>\n";

console.log(r);
```

**Output:**

```
<ul>
<li> Submittals in progress </li>
<li> Structural works in progress in S2 & S3 </li>
<li> Structural works in progress in N4. </li>
<li> Childrens Mall pedestal and steel fabrication. </li>
</ul>
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dD0vT3/3)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\b\d+              # match 1 or more digits after a word boundary
\.                 # match one literal dot
\s+                # match 1 or more space
(.+?)              # match 1 or more any character and capture it group #1
\s*                # match 0 or more spaces
(?=...)            # a positive lookahead
(?=\b\d+\. |\s*$)  # match must be followed by a word boundary + digits + dot OR
                   # white spaces + line end
```

---

**Update:** To get an array of matched items from original string use `String#match` as:

```
var arr = s.match( /\b\d+\.\s+(.+?)(?=\s*\b\d+\. |\s*$)/g );
```

This will give:

```
["1. Submittals in progress",
 "2. Structural works in progress in S2 & S3",
 "3. Structural works in progress in N4.",
 "4. Childrens Mall pedestal and steel fabrication."]
```

Comment: if the each lines are convert in to an array, that would be fine

Comment: I need as a array, so i can iterate in agnualrjs. it should be like this : ["....", "...." etc]

Comment: This output is exactly as per your question. If you want to break it up into arrays then see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

To do the same thing which was suggested by anubhava dynamically. you could use `list#appendChild`.

Create a function, pass your string and the list item to append to.

```js
var strs = "1. Submittals in progress 2. Structural works in progress in S2 & S3 3. Structural works in progress in N4. 4. Childrens Mall pedestal and steel fabrication.".match(
 /\b\d+\.\s+(.+?)\s*(?=\b\d+\. |\s*$)/g);

var list = document.getElementById('list');
for (var i in strs) {
  var anchor = document.createElement("a");
  anchor.href = "#";
  anchor.innerText = strs[i];

  var elem = document.createElement("li");
  elem.appendChild(anchor);
  list.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```html
<ul id = "list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

PS: anchors added just to show a sample on how that can also be changed.